# Page looks fine locally. But when pushed to server everything is zoomed in

Tags: html, css, node.js

So this has been bugging me for some time and I can't seem to get it so thought Id ask here.

Basically I am working on a node app and it looks fine when I am looking at it locally but when I push it to my server (linode) and run it there everything is zoomed in (see screenshots). What would/could be causing this. Thanks. The first one is how it looks when on server and other on local.
[image: Server]

[image: Local]

Comment: Same browser? Same CSS? Same HTML? You should check all of those off. Seems like some CSS may not be pushed to the server correctly (wrong directory name somewhere?)

Comment: Yup same everything. hmm ok it should all be there but ill check.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but have you accidentially zoomed in on your server site and your browser is caching the zoom level? Try doing a CTRL+0 (zero)

Comment: ... hah. thanks a lot!! if you want to submit that as an answer i'll accept it. That was embarrassing lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As from my comment earlier (before I had to head out)...

Try reseting the zoom level on the browser for the server site by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> (thats a zero).

(It's always the stupid ones that frustrate you the most ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It should be because of Zoomed In! Try pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> so it should work now! :)

Else, `View` » `Zoom` » `100%`.

This should work! :)